# Chrome Extension Native messaging syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have an issue where my chrome extension, when attempting to communicate with the native host application, returns this error. Specifically when passing a helo message to ensure the host app is installed.

---

> Error: Invocation of form runtime.sendNativeMessage(string, string, function) doesn't match definition runtime.sendNativeMessage(string application, object message, optional function responseCallback)
>       at chrome-extension://lafoonpfkflnebpoacdbcojcbdhebifh/background.js:35:20

---

I have tried passing a preexisting object, an object defined in the sendNativeMessage such as sendNativeMessage(string,{object:"object"},function) and an object recently defined via new object.

EDIT: I have also tried var nativeMessageObject = {};

I feel like i must be barking up the wrong tree or something here. Below is my code currently trimmed to just the relevant area.

---

```
console.log("Recieved helo host app. Attempting to contact host app.")

var nativeMessageObject = new Object();
nativeMessageObject.data = "helo";
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('appName', nativeMessageObject, function(response) {
  console.log("Host app responded: " + response)
  switch (response) {
    case "ehlo":
      console.log("Host app responded with ehlo")
      sendResponse({
        data: "ehlo host app"
      })
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Error: " + Json.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError))
      sendResponse({
        data: "Error: " + Json.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError)
      })
      break;
  }
})
```

---

Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT: Have now tried across 3 different machines, error is the same in all cases.

Comment: Try `var nativeMessageObject = {};`

Comment: I hadn't tried this specific variation but now that iv tested it, no change, i appreciate the rapid response though.

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome then. Try in an older portable version.

Comment: Just finished testing that idea, no dice.

Comment: You can use ``chrome.extension.sendMessage`` to send message to your native messaging host. Just specify the ID of your native messaging host in first parameter.

Comment: I did not know that, i take it you are suggesting using sendMessage instead of sendNativeMessage to attempt to work around the error? Ill give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: When looking into your suggestion @Asesh i cant see how to implement it. Are you certain you can use sendMessage to communicate from a chrome extension to a natively installed application?  

sendMessage takes an extension or app ID from the chrome store, however sendNativeMessage just uses a name that is looked for in registry to find the program.

Comment: Yes you can but it must be from background page, not sure if it will work from popup page. Here's how to use it: ``chrome.extension.sendMessage('your_extension_id', {type : 'logout', success : true});``

Comment: @Asesh so what would be the extension id in the situation where my extension is sending a message to a native messaging app installed on the machine? Since a native messaging host doesn't have an extension id im not sure what that first parameter should be.

Comment: By ``your_extension_id`` I was referring to your native messaging host ID. Native messaging host will have an extension ID too

Comment: To see your native messaging host's extension ID, goto this page: ``chrome://extensions/`` and then enable developer mode. Then you will see it's extension ID

Comment: Also I apologies for my comment's formatting, having trouble getting the formatting on here to work.

Comment: @Asesh I think we are have a disconnect in terms then. What I am trying to do is use a chrome extension that i wrote to send a message to a C# application that i wrote that is installed independently of chrome. This "native host app" is not registered with chrome or chrome webstore and is instead launched by the chrome browser when using sendNativeMessage by looking up the first parameter of sendNativeMessage in the windows registry to find a pointer to the .exe that chrome then runs and passes the message to the standard input of.

Comment: The Native Host App in this is never given any form of ID like that of a chrome extension

Comment: Tried a few other ideas for this but no matter what i do i still get this error from `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`